# Get a 3D point cloud from depth image

Tags: c#, c++, kinect, point-clouds

I hope to develop a program to get a kinect depth image and convert it into 3D [point cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud) as my final year project.

I have to write a program to save those depth images into bin directory of the project. But I'm unable to convert those images to 3d point cloud.

If anyone has an idea about how to implement this or any working projects for that please help me.

Comment: You're going to need to give us more specifics. What have you tried already, why are you unable to convert them?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you check out [PCL library](http://www.pointclouds.org/). It's open project for 3D point cloud processing, and it's quite well-documented. There are many tutorials, but for your task you should take look at:

- [Kinect OpenNI tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php) (fast access to point cloud using PCL and OpenNI library)

Answer (score 2):

See [i-programmer](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c/4126-kinect-sdk1-a-3d-point-cloud.html?start=2) for how to make a point-cloud. And if you just want to make one and not understand it(which I strongly **don't** advise), here is the code:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PointCloudWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Point Cloud" Height="653" Width="993" Background="Black" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Height="1130" Width="1626">
    <Canvas Height="611" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="967" Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using Microsoft.Kinect;


namespace PointCloudWPF
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    GeometryModel3D[] points = new GeometryModel3D[320 * 240];
    int s = 4;
    KinectSensor sensor;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    void DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        DepthImageFrame imageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
        if (imageFrame != null)
        {
            short[] pixelData = new short[imageFrame.PixelDataLength];
            imageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
            int temp = 0;
            int i = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < 240; y += s)
                for (int x = 0; x < 320; x += s)
                {
                    temp = ((ushort)pixelData[x + y * 320]) >> 3;
                    ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetZ = temp;
                    i++;
                }
        }
    }


    private GeometryModel3D Triangle(double x, double y, double s, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        Point3DCollection corners = new Point3DCollection();
        corners.Add(new Point3D(x, y, 0));
        corners.Add(new Point3D(x, y + s, 0));
        corners.Add(new Point3D(x + s, y + s, 0));

        Int32Collection Triangles = new Int32Collection();
        Triangles.Add(0);
        Triangles.Add(1);
        Triangles.Add(2);

        MeshGeometry3D tmesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
        tmesh.Positions = corners;
        tmesh.TriangleIndices = Triangles;
        tmesh.Normals.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, -1));

        GeometryModel3D msheet = new GeometryModel3D();
        msheet.Geometry = tmesh;
        msheet.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(color);
        return msheet;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DirectionalLight DirLight1 = new DirectionalLight();
        DirLight1.Color = Colors.White;
        DirLight1.Direction = new Vector3D(1, 1, 1);


        PerspectiveCamera Camera1 = new PerspectiveCamera();
        Camera1.FarPlaneDistance = 8000;
        Camera1.NearPlaneDistance = 100;
        Camera1.FieldOfView = 10;
        Camera1.Position = new Point3D(160, 120, -1000);
        Camera1.LookDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
        Camera1.UpDirection = new Vector3D(0, -1, 0);

        Model3DGroup modelGroup = new Model3DGroup();

        int i = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 240; y += s)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 320; x += s)
            {
                points[i] = Triangle(x, y, s, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
                // points[i]=MCube(x,y);
                points[i].Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 0, 0);
                modelGroup.Children.Add(points[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        modelGroup.Children.Add(DirLight1);
        ModelVisual3D modelsVisual = new ModelVisual3D();
        modelsVisual.Content = modelGroup;
        Viewport3D myViewport = new Viewport3D();
        myViewport.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        myViewport.Camera = Camera1;
        myViewport.Children.Add(modelsVisual);
        canvas1.Children.Add(myViewport);

        myViewport.Height = canvas1.Height;
        myViewport.Width = canvas1.Width;
        Canvas.SetTop(myViewport, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myViewport, 0);

        sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        sensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30);
        sensor.DepthFrameReady += DepthFrameReady;
        sensor.Start();

    }
}
}
```